# Should I say "I will be using" or "I am using" in conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I am in Figi next week, I will be using my scuba diving gear.
>
> If I am in Figi next week, I am using my scuba diving gear. (maybe incorrect)

I think the second sentence is incorrect. Can you point out why?

Comment: Hi Graduate, please add more information because as it stands your question is simply proofreading! Can you point out which sentences you think might be correct, or what you're trying to convey with each, or where you think there might be a mistake? (If there are other problems beyond those you suspect, we will be sure to point them out, but we require you have at least one specific concern first.)

Comment: Do you mean [Fiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiji), rather than Figi?

Answer (score 7):

*If I am in Figi next week, I will use my scuba diving gear.*

This sentence meets the grammatical requirement of First Conditional.

Source: [EnglishClub | First Conditional: real possibility](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional_2.htm).

Comment: I don't understand why this should get even *one* downvote, let alone ***two***. Have my upvote to help redress the balance!

Comment: @Fumble, agree. +1 to get the answer balanced.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Probably got the down-vote because he didn't say "why". Not a good enough reason though, because the answer is correct and the link explains the 1st conditional well.

Comment: I'm not one of the down-voters, but I can understand it easily enough. The answer as written doesn't fully address the question, whether original or edit. It's an answer, and it's a good one, but it's not a direct answer to the question as it's written. Certainly not deserving of a down-vote, of course.

Comment: It seems one of the downvotes has now been reversed anyway. Personally, I usually only *downvote* if an answer is actually ***wrong***, not just because it's "inadequate". But I do agree that in situations like this answers should normally copy or paraphrase important points made in any links.

Answer (score 0):

In the second answer you are referring to a possible future event, then stating a dependent action in the present instead of the future.

Personally I would use "If I'm in Fiji next week, I'll use my scuba diving gear."

As an alternative, you could also use "If I am in Fiji next week, I am going to *use/be using* my scuba diving gear.".